# mysql group by query with average calculation

Tags: mysql

```
id originator revenue date
-- ---------- ------- ----------
1  acme             1 2013-09-15
2  acme             0 2013-09-15
3  acme             4 2013-09-14
4  acme             6 2013-09-13
5  acme            -6 2013-09-13
6  hello            1 2013-09-15
7  hello            0 2013-09-14
8  hello            2 2013-09-13
9  hello            5 2013-09-14
```

I have the above table . And I would like to add the ranking column  based on the revenue generated by the originator based on the revenue for last 3 days

the fields to be displayed as below:

```
originator revenue toprank
---------- ------- -------
hello            8       1
acme             5       2
```

2) And based on the above data , i would like to calculate the avg revenue generated based on the following criteria

If the sum of total revenue for the same date is 0 ( zero) then it should not be counted with calculating the average.

a) avg value for originator acme should be sum of  revenue/count(no of dates where the revenue is non zero value) so (4+1)/2 i.e 2.5

b) avg value for originator hello should be sum of  revenue/count(no of dates where the revenue is non zero value) so (5+2+1)/3 i.e 2.6666

```
originator revenue toprank avg(3 days)
---------- ------- ------- -----------
hello            8       1      2.6666
acme             5       2      2.5
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql group by with avg calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867645/mysql-group-by-with-avg-calculation)

Answer (score 0):

To ignore a row when averaging, give `AVG` a null value. The [`NULLIF` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) is good for this.

The ranking is problematic in MySQL. It doesn't support analytic functions that make this a bit easier to do in Oracle, MySQL, Teradata, etc. The most common workaround is to use a counter variable, and that requires an ordered set of rows, which means the total revenue must be calculated in an inner query.

```
SELECT originator, TotalRev, Avg3Days, @rnk := @rnk + 1 AS TopRank
FROM (
  SELECT
    originator,
    SUM(revenue) AS TotalRev,
    AVG(NULLIF(revenue, 0)) AS Avg3Days
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY originator
  ORDER BY TotalRev DESC
) Tots, (SELECT @rnk := 0) Ranks
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values for the **last 3 days from today's date**, try something like this:

```
SET @rank=0;

select originator, rev, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, avg 
FROM 
(select originator, sum(revenue) as rev, 
AVG(NULLIF(revenue, 0)) as avg
FROM t1
WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
group by originator
order by 2 desc) as t2;
```

**[SQL Fiddle..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6bf88/17/1)**

### EDITED:

If you want to get the values for the **last 3 days from the nearest date**, try this:

```
SET @rank=0;

select originator, rev, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, avg 
from 
(select originator, sum(revenue) as rev, 
AVG(NULLIF(revenue, 0)) as avg
from t1
WHERE date >= DATE_ADD((select max(date) from t1), INTERVAL -3 DAY)
group by originator
order by 2 desc) as t2;
```

**[SQL Fiddle..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fb30a/4/1)**

Comment: I just changed the table .. and needed the same output

Comment: @user1927716 what do you mean by `last 3 days`? is it from today's date or from the nearest date or what?

Comment: basically first we will calculate the top 10 originators based on the revenue for today and the average will be from yesterday to last 7 days so in short if originator is having top rank for today i.e 2013-09-18 then its avg revenue should be calculated  for 17,16,15,14,13,12,11 dates and lets say it dint had any revenue collected on 15 and 14 then its average to be calculated as total revenue from 17 till 11 and then divide it by 5 as it dint collect anything on 15 and 14

Comment: basically the avg that u r calculating is based on the no of rows this particular record appears and then u r dividing it so the avg that u get is too low ...

Comment: @user1927716 do you need it to be divided to all the rows or just not 0 rows? or what do you need?

Comment: @user1927716 btw, the avg of `acme` is `(1+4+6-6)/4` that's why your'e getting a low avg.