# mysql group by with avg calculation

Tags: mysql

```
id originator revenue date

1  acme             1 2013-09-15
2  acme             0 2013-09-15
3  acme             4 2013-09-14
4  acme             6 2013-09-13
5  acme            -6 2013-09-13
6  hello            1 2013-09-15
7  hello            0 2013-09-14
8  hello            2 2013-09-13
9  hello            5 2013-09-14
```

I have the above table . And I would like to add the ranking column based on the revenue generated by the originator based on the revenue for last 3 days

the fields to be displayed as below:

```
originator revenue toprank

hello            8       1
acme             5       2
```

2) And based on the above data , i would like to calculate the avg revenue generated based on the following criteria

If the sum of total revenue for the same date is **0** ( zero) then it should not be counted with calculating the average.

a) avg value for originator acme should be sum of revenue/count(no of dates where the revenue is non zero value) so **(4+1)/2 i.e 2.5**

b) avg value for originator hello should be sum of revenue/count(no of dates where the revenue is non zero value) so **(5+2+1)/3** i.e **2.6666**

```
originator revenue toprank avg(3 days)

hello            8       1      2.6666
acme             5       2      2.5
```

Comment: did you try anything yourself?

Comment: yes .. but we tried it with static value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to group the records by date in order to find the daily totals and exclude those days that have a total sum of zero.

Then use that query as a subquery from which you group again to get the totals and averages by originator.

Finally, perform the ranking (either in your application code as you loop over the resultset, or else in MySQL using an outer query with user variables).

```
SELECT originator, revenue, @r:=@r+1 AS toprank, avg FROM (
  SELECT   originator, SUM(total) AS revenue, AVG(total) AS avg
  FROM (
    SELECT   originator, date, SUM(revenue) AS total
    FROM     my_table
--  WHERE    date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE
    GROUP BY originator, date
    HAVING   total <> 0
  ) t
  GROUP BY originator
  ORDER BY revenue DESC
) t, (SELECT @r:=0) init
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82d39/1/0).

Comment: thanks eggyal .. but i need the the where clause to be included as i have to calculate the average based on last 3 days and also based on the conditions that i described in my question

Comment: @user1927716: I only commented it out so that "last three days" doesn't exclude the dates in the sample data.

Comment: basically first we will calculate the top 10 originators based on the revenue for today and the average will be from yesterday to last 7 days so in short if originator is having top rank for today i.e 2013-09-18 then its avg revenue should be calculated for 17,16,15,14,13,12,11 dates and lets say it dint had any revenue collected on 15 and 14 then its average to be calculated as total revenue from 17 till 11 and then divide it by 5 as it dint collect anything on 15 and 14

Comment: @user1927716: In that case, replace my commented clause with `WHERE originator IN (SELECT originator FROM my_table WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE GROUP BY originator ORDER BY SUM(revenue) DESC LIMIT 10) AND date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY`.